# Automapper: Can I use the same rule created by CreateMap to map both ways?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm a little confuse about the direction of the mapping.

This is the create mapping.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Dimension, PostedDimensionViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.inputDimension, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.DimensionName))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.inputDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(p => p.Description));
```

Then I can use it this way to go from **PostedDimensionViewModel => Dimension**:

```
Dimension dimension = Mapper.Map<PostedDimensionViewModel, Dimension>(model);
```

What if, I want to go from **Dimension => PostedDimensionViewModel**, do I need another **CreateMap** or I can just use the same above mapping from both directions?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Be wary, often the desire to do a "two-way" mapping like this is indicative of an anemic domain model (http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)

Comment: You will need to create another map. (I use this to pre-fill ViewModels that contain form data, so it's not always an anemic domain, just separation of your domain from your view data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    /* your other stuff here */
    .ReverseMap();
```

There are limitations here, and I wouldn't recommend this except between two DTOs.

Comment: Listen to this guy @Richard77, he may of had a hand in the building of AutoMapper :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to provide an additional map if you intend to go in the other direction. If you try to use AutoMapper without the extra map you'll get an exception:

> AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
>
> PostedDimensionViewModel -> Dimension